# How to repeat a list of items in a range based on a specified value for each item in the range ing google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to repeat a list in google sheets where each item is repeated a different number of times based on a value in a different cell.

What formula can I use to achieve this?

List:
Apple
Banana
Orange

Desired Output:
Apple
Apple
Banana
Banana
Banana
Banana
Orange
Orange
Orange

| Items | # of rept |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 |
| Banana | 4 |
| Orange | 3 |

=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(D2:D42),10),D2:D42)))

This is all I can think of but the 10 needs to be a custom value depending on the value associated with the unique cell in D2:D42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(SPLIT(JOIN(,REPT(A2:A&"ζ",B2:B)),"ζ")))
```

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(SEQUENCE(1,b),a))),3))
```

```
=TOCOL(MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(a,b,CHOOSECOLS(a,SEQUENCE(1,b,1,0)))),3)
```

Comment: Works great! Do you mind explaining what you are doing so I understand?